# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE causing large increment gaps - InnoDB MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert keywords into a `keyword` table and map them to `articles` via a `articleKeywordIndex` table, but have got stuck in a rut and can't get out. This is my setup:

```
articles
-------------
articleID    INT AUTO PRI

articleKeywordIndex
-------------
articleID    INT UNIQUE
keywordID    INT UNIQUE

keywords
-------------
keywordID    INT PRI
keyword      VARCHAR UNIQUE
```

I *was* using `INSERT INTO keywords (a) VALUES (:a) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = a` but I noticed that the auto-increment was strangely being updated and that confused me, as I thought that was the method for that not to happen. Anyway, I also need to grab the `keywordID` whether it exists or not, to put into the mixer table, so I went for a try/catch solution instead, where if the INSERT fails due to a unique entry, the catch would SELECT that keywordID to use in the other table.

What's happening now, is if the keyword does NOT already exist, and there are already 4 keywords in that table (1,2,3,4), the keywordID column in the keyword table gets incremented by 4, making it 8 when it gets inserted. If this keeps happen and I've got lots of keywords, the keywordID column's ID will be huuuuge! If the keyword DOES exist, nothing changes and works perfectly. I'd imagine it has something to do with the loop looping 4 times, but I cannot see the problem.

Here's the code:

```
$tagsArray = explode(',', strtolower($tags));
for ($x = 0; $x < count($tagsArray); $x++) {

    $keyword = trim($tagsArray[$x]);

    try {
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO keywords (keyword) VALUES (:keyword);";
        $STH = $DBH -> prepare($SQL);
        $STH -> bindParam(':keyword', $keyword);
        $STH -> execute();
        $keywordID = $DBH -> lastInsertId();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $SQL = "SELECT keywordID FROM keywords WHERE keyword = :keyword;";
        $STH = $DBH -> prepare($SQL);
        $STH -> bindParam(':keyword', $keyword);
        $STH -> execute();
        $keywordID = $STH -> fetchColumn();
    }

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO articleKeywordIndex (articleID, keywordID) VALUES (:saveToID, :keywordID)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE articleID = articleID, keywordID = keywordID;";
    $STH = $DBH -> prepare($SQL);
    $STH -> bindParam(':saveToID', $saveToID);
    $STH -> bindParam(':keywordID', $keywordID);
    $STH -> execute();

}
```

I suppose it's not a great deal, as I'll only ever ~3000-5000 keywords, but it's still annoying and would like to learn what is wrong.

**THE SOLUTION**

It turns out that using the InnoDB engine causes odd incremental changes when using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This was actually reported as a bug a few years ago and a patch was distributed, but then it turned out to be a purposely designed feature and a setting in my.cnf disables it. Quite an odd story and took a while to learn about it. Anyway, in `my.cnf`, I changed this:

`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0`

And all is back to normal and my script works as I thought it would when I first wrote it, before the other five attempts!! I'm using InnoDB for transactions, so I wasn't prepared to switch to MyISAM just because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using the InnoDB engine causes odd incremental changes when using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. This was actually reported as a bug a few years ago and a patch was distributed, but then it turned out to be a purposely designed feature and a setting in my.cnf disables it. Quite an odd story and took a while to learn about it. Anyway, in `my.cnf`, I changed this:

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
```

And all is back to normal. I'm using InnoDB for transactions, so I wasn't prepared to switch to MyISAM just because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok? I'll probably try the following and see if anything works.

- First, check the auto_increment_increment with `SELECT @@auto_increment_increment;`. Maybe it was set to 4 for some reason?
- What if you add records using mySQL manually? Does it still go up by 4? If yes then maybe it's not about your code.
- You said it might have something to do with the loop looping 4 times. Have you tried using a makeup array for the loop with say...6 elements? does it goes up by 6?
- I'd also check and make sure there isn't any hidden procedures or triggers that is doing stuff under the hood.

EDIT1: moved prepare out of loop. I think since both with or without `on update` you still seems to have odd increment value issue, might as well use  `...on update` again

```
$tagsArray = explode(',', strtolower($tags));
$SQL = "INSERT INTO keywords (keywordID, keyword) VALUES (NULL, :keyword) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE keywordID=LAST_INSERT_ID(keywordID), keyword = keyword;
        INSERT INTO articleKeywordIndex (articleID, keywordID) VALUES (:saveToID, LAST_INSERT_ID())
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE articleID = articleID, keywordID = keywordID;";
$STH = $DBH -> prepare($SQL);
$STH -> bindParam(':saveToID', $saveToID);   //<--I actually haven't tried this, if it doesn't work move it back into loop.

for ($x = 0; $x < count($tagsArray); $x++) {
        $STH -> bindParam(':keyword', trim($tagsArray[$x]));
        $STH -> execute();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacky, thanks for sharing some tips. I've manually inserted database records and the increments are all working fine - so it's definitely my code. I've worked out that if a keyword gets inserted (in the TRY block), it gets incremented by the total amount of keywords I'm submitting in total, basically the number of loops.

Comment: take a look at the new edit. The important part is the `keywordID=LAST_INSERT_ID(keywordID)`, maybe this will work. Also, just to be very sure, when the odd increment happens does `articleKeywordIndex.keywordID` AND `keywords.keywordID` BOTH got affected or is it only 1 of them?

Comment: It's just `keywords.keywordID` that is affected. I really appreciate your help on this. I will give this a try in 10 minutes.

Comment: Okay, so I tested it and it came back with an error which I've never experienced before, and failed. I tested it trying to save two keywords; the first keyword saved to the `keywords` table okay but then it failed before it saved to `articleKeywordIndex`, and obviously didn't reach the second keyword. **Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute**

Comment: Jacky, thank you so much for your efforts, but I have just discovered the cause of my problem. I'm using the InnoDB engine on this table, as I have a bunch of important inserts/updates queries which I've put inside a transaction. After digging very hard, it turns out InnoDB has odd behaviour when dealing with duplicated inserts, increasing the auto-incremented ID even on failed inserts. I just rebuilt this table using MyISAM, tested it, and it now works perfectly. Now I now the root, I can come up with a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: My solution was to continue using InnoDB to give me transactions, but I changed a setting `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` in `my.cnf` which fixes this increment issue. Now working fine.

Comment: hey~ glad you got out alive. By the way, it's OK in SO to "answer" your own question and mark your own solution as accepted. I'd actually suggest you doing that instead of accepting mine, thanks for upvote for effort thou :D